# Android bluetooth? различие версий

Tags: android, bluetooth

Сделал приложение по примеру, которое ищет по BT и соединяет два устройства. Однако на устройствах android 5.1 и 4.4.2 метод поиска устройств и добавление их в лист работает, а вот 6.0 не может найти ни одного.
 Код метода

```
 public void discoverDevices(View view) {
    if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        // Bluetooth выключен. Предложим пользователю включить его.
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, RESULT_OK);
    }
    discoveredDevices.clear();
    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    if (discoverDevicesReceiver == null) {
        discoverDevicesReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();

                if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                    BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                    if (!discoveredDevices.contains(device)) {
                        discoveredDevices.add(device);
                        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }

    if (discoveryFinishedReceiver == null) {
        discoveryFinishedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                getListView().setEnabled(true);
                if (progressDialog != null)
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Поиск закончен. Выберите устройство для отправки ообщения.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                unregisterReceiver(discoveryFinishedReceiver);
            }
        };
    }

    registerReceiver(discoverDevicesReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
    registerReceiver(discoveryFinishedReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED));

    getListView().setEnabled(false);

    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Поиск устройств", "Подождите...");

    bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
}
```

Comment: Permissions для работы с bluetooth запрашиваете в рантайме?

Comment: @eugeneek нет, я их задаю в manifeste, и больше ничего с ними не делаю. android 6.0  как сервер работает, а найти не может.

Comment: А нужно делать на 6.0+. Почитайте [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: @eugeneek Вот оно что, так и думал, что с версией связано. Оформи как ответ, приму. Мои разрешения <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permission  `Bluetooth` и `Bluetooth_Admin` являются безопасными, их в Runtume вызывать не нужно.

ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION является `Dengerous` поэтому перед вызовом поиска устройств, необходимо запросить разрешение

```
 int PERMISSION_REQUEST=0;
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                PERMISSION_REQUEST);
```